# Java, how to replace some characters in String

Tags: android, string, url, replace

I have an array that keeps URL addresses in String format for me.
Before loading URLs, I need to make sure that there is no space in strings.
I wrote this code but ReplaceAll() doesn't change anything.

Please tell me what is wrong here?

```
public NewsFeedItemList getNewsList() {
        String str;

        for(int i=0; i<newsFeedItemList.getImage().size(); i++){
            str = newsFeedItemList.getImage().get(i);
            Log.i("before>>>", str);
            str.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            Log.i("after<<<<", str);
            newsFeedItemList.getImage().set(i, str);
        }

        return newsFeedItemList;
    }
```

Comment: Actually when i test my android app, it crashed. When i checked the log it showed me that one of urls is like this: "http://www.mania.com.my/Portals/1/hazama_news 20(1).jpg" When i put it in browser, browser changed it to "http://www.mania.com.my/Portals/1/hazama_news%20(1).jpg". I put above code in somewhere in my app but nothing will change.

Comment: suggestion dont use `replace` method, using `str = URLEncoder.encode(str)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are immutable, meaning that you cannot change the contents of a String object. What you would need to do is something like

```
String cleanedString = str.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

The replaceAll()-Method returns the new String.

Answer (score 2):

String is immutable, so you need to assign it back like this: `str = str.replaceAll(" ", "%20");`

Answer (score 2):

As already said by the other posters: String is immutable so you have to assign the return value of `replaceAll` to String.

Just as a hint: you should take a look at `java.net.URLEncoder`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

This class helps you to format the url in a correct way and can handle all kinds of special characters - not only spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace the line

```
str.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

with

```
str=str.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated your code with the following code,

public NewsFeedItemList getNewsList() {
        String str;

```
    for(int i=0; i<newsFeedItemList.getImage().size(); i++){
        str = newsFeedItemList.getImage().get(i);
        Log.i("before>>>", str);
        str = str.replaceAll(" ", "%20");  // I have update here
        Log.i("after<<<<", str);
        newsFeedItemList.getImage().set(i, str);
    }

    return newsFeedItemList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

suggestion dont use `replace` method,

using `str = URLEncoder.encode(str)`,

sometimes not only the space and have another need changed character.